# using standard normal deviation to calculate mean?

Tags: normal-distribution

if i have an unknown mean, a standard deviation of 4, and P(X < 8 ) = 0.3085, how do I calculate the mean **somehow using the standard normal distribution and it's cummulative function?**

I know that P(x<8 ) = 0.3085 is the same as Phi((8 - mean)/4) = 0.3085, and now I want to isolate the mean. I can firstly remove phi on the left side by using it's inverse function phi^-1, but how do I take the phi^-1(0.3085)?

I have no idea how to do it on a calculator, software, no nothing....

Comment: Why not look up the $z-$ value associated with .3085. This will tell you have many $\sigma$ s away from the mean the value $8$ is. Checking in a Standard Normal table, you see that Z=-0.5 (approx.) has that property, i.e., P(Z< -0.5) ~.3085. So your value is 1/2 deviation from the mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at a Standard Normal table, e.g., http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-normal-distribution-table.html , you can see that the probability, i.e., p-value, corresponds to , approximately, $Z=-0.5$. Then , using $X=8$, $\sigma=4$, you have: $$\frac{8-\mu}{4}=-0.5$$, so that $\mu=10$.